# Airflow with Python creating dynamic tasks

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to make a dynamic workflow. 
I've got this:

[image: Airflow]
I try to dynamically creating tasks using BashOperator(which calling python script)

My dag:

```
import datetime as dt
from airflow import DAG
import shutil
import os
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator

scriptAirflow = '/home/alexw/scriptAirflow/'
uploadPath='/apps/lv-manuf2020-data/80_DATA/00_Loading/'
receiptPath= '/apps/lv-manuf2020-data/80_DATA/01_Receipt/'
fmsFiles=[]
memFiles=[]

def onlyCsvFiles():
    if(os.listdir(uploadPath)):
        for files in os.listdir(uploadPath):    
            if(files.startswith('MEM') and files.endswith('.csv') or files.startswith('FMS') and files.endswith('.csv')):
                shutil.move(uploadPath+files, receiptPath)
                print(files+' moved in ' + receiptPath+files)
        for files in os.listdir(receiptPath):
            if(files.startswith('MEM') and files.endswith('.csv') or files.startswith('FMS') and files.endswith('.csv')):
                return "run_scripts"
            else:
                return "no_script"
    else:
        print('No file in upload_00')



default_args = {
    'owner': 'manuf2020',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2020, 2, 17),
    'retries': 1,
}


dag = DAG('lv-manuf2020', default_args=default_args, description='airflow_manuf2020',
          schedule_interval=None, catchup=False)


file_sensor = FileSensor(
    task_id="file_sensor",
    filepath=uploadPath,
    fs_conn_id='airflow_db',
    poke_interval=10,
    dag=dag,
)


move_csv = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='move_csv',
    python_callable=onlyCsvFiles,
    trigger_rule='none_failed',
    dag=dag,
)

run_scripts = DummyOperator(
    task_id="run_scripts",
    dag=dag
)

no_script= TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='no_script',
    trigger_dag_id='lv-manuf2020',
    trigger_rule='all_done',
    dag=dag,
)

if os.listdir(receiptPath):
    for files in os.listdir(receiptPath):
        if files.startswith('FMS') and files.endswith('.csv'):
            fmsFiles.append(files)
        if files.startswith('MEM') and files.endswith('.csv'):
            memFiles.append(files)
else:
    pass

for files in fmsFiles:
    run_Fms_Script = BashOperator(
        task_id="fms_script_"+files,
        bash_command='python3 '+scriptAirflow+'fmsScript.py "{{ execution_date }}"',
        dag=dag,
    )
    rerun_dag=TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='rerun_dag',
        trigger_dag_id='lv-manuf2020',
        trigger_rule='none_failed',
        dag=dag,
    )
    run_scripts.set_downstream(run_Fms_Script)
    rerun_dag.set_upstream(run_Fms_Script)

for files in memFiles:
    run_Mem_Script = BashOperator(
        task_id="mem_script_"+files,
        bash_command='python3 '+scriptAirflow+'memShScript.py "{{ execution_date }}"',
        dag=dag,
    )
    rerun_dag=TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='rerun_dag',
        trigger_dag_id='lv-manuf2020',
        trigger_rule='none_failed',
        dag=dag,
    )
    run_scripts.set_downstream(run_Mem_Script)
    rerun_dag.set_upstream(run_Mem_Script)






move_csv.set_upstream(file_sensor)
run_scripts.set_upstream(move_csv)
no_script.set_upstream(move_csv)
```

It's doesn't work like i'd like to. In this loop, it's calling a Python script which is suppose to launch a Sh script. It's creating the task, but immediately after it's rerun the dag without launching my script.

```
for files in memFiles:
    run_Mem_Script = BashOperator(
        task_id="mem_script_"+files,
        bash_command='python3 '+scriptAirflow+'memShScript.py "{{ execution_date }}"',
        dag=dag,
    )
    rerun_dag=TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='rerun_dag',
        trigger_dag_id='lv-manuf2020',
        trigger_rule='none_failed',
        dag=dag,
    )
    run_scripts.set_downstream(run_Mem_Script)
    rerun_dag.set_upstream(run_Mem_Script)
```

can someone tell me, how to create dynamic tasks in parallel if necessary using BashOperator ('cause i call my python script like this)
I need something like

file_sensor >> move_csv >> run_scripts >> dymanic_task >> rerun_dag

Comment: The last code snippet is just the rest of the python file?

Comment: yes, the rest of my dag file, just a zoom on it, because its where is my problem

Answer (score 0):

All the code ran just once when you created the DAG file, only `onlyCsvFiles` function runs periodically as part of a task.
Airflow imports your python file which runs the interpreter and creates .pyc file next to the original .py file of your DAG, and since the code isn't changing, airflow will not run the DAG's code again and always use the same .pyc file on the next imports.

> .pyc files are created by the Python interpreter when a .py file is imported.
>   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-pyc-files-in-Python

In order to add or change the tasks of the DAG, you must create a process that runs the interpreter periodically and updates the .pyc file.
There are several ways to do it, the best approach is to utilize airflow to do so.

I'm not suggesting other way to create dynamic tasks, so with this attitude, you need to create another task which triggers interpretation of your python file, to "refresh" the .pyc file with the potential new tasks; they represented in runtime inside this loop:

```
for files in memFiles:
    run_Mem_Script = BashOperator(
        task_id="mem_script_"+files,
        bash_command='python3 '+scriptAirflow+'memShScript.py "{{ execution_date }}"',
        dag=dag,
    )
    rerun_dag=TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='rerun_dag',
        trigger_dag_id='lv-manuf2020',
        trigger_rule='none_failed',
        dag=dag,
    )
```

python command triggers interpretation and updated the .pyc file.
Create independent task in your DAG as follows (edit bash command with your DAG's absolute path):

```
interpret_python = BashOperator(
    task_id="interpret_python",
    bash_command='python3 /path/to/this/file.py',
    dag=dag,
)
```

I would not suggest to find a python function which gets the current file path because you may get the airflow's running path since it imports your code, though it can maybe work.

Your new code: (I only added the `interpret_python` task to your code, remember to replace `/path/to/this/file.py` with your DAG file's absolute path):

```
import datetime as dt
from airflow import DAG
import shutil
import os
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator

scriptAirflow = '/home/alexw/scriptAirflow/'
uploadPath='/apps/lv-manuf2020-data/80_DATA/00_Loading/'
receiptPath= '/apps/lv-manuf2020-data/80_DATA/01_Receipt/'
fmsFiles=[]
memFiles=[]

def onlyCsvFiles():
    if(os.listdir(uploadPath)):
        for files in os.listdir(uploadPath):    
            if(files.startswith('MEM') and files.endswith('.csv') or files.startswith('FMS') and files.endswith('.csv')):
                shutil.move(uploadPath+files, receiptPath)
                print(files+' moved in ' + receiptPath+files)
        for files in os.listdir(receiptPath):
            if(files.startswith('MEM') and files.endswith('.csv') or files.startswith('FMS') and files.endswith('.csv')):
                return "run_scripts"
            else:
                return "no_script"
    else:
        print('No file in upload_00')



default_args = {
    'owner': 'manuf2020',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2020, 2, 17),
    'retries': 1,
}


dag = DAG('lv-manuf2020', default_args=default_args, description='airflow_manuf2020',
          schedule_interval=None, catchup=False)


file_sensor = FileSensor(
    task_id="file_sensor",
    filepath=uploadPath,
    fs_conn_id='airflow_db',
    poke_interval=10,
    dag=dag,
)


move_csv = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='move_csv',
    python_callable=onlyCsvFiles,
    trigger_rule='none_failed',
    dag=dag,
)

run_scripts = DummyOperator(
    task_id="run_scripts",
    dag=dag
)

no_script= TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='no_script',
    trigger_dag_id='lv-manuf2020',
    trigger_rule='all_done',
    dag=dag,
)

interpret_python = BashOperator(
    task_id="interpret_python",
    bash_command='python3 /path/to/this/file.py',
    dag=dag,
)

if os.listdir(receiptPath):
    for files in os.listdir(receiptPath):
        if files.startswith('FMS') and files.endswith('.csv'):
            fmsFiles.append(files)
        if files.startswith('MEM') and files.endswith('.csv'):
            memFiles.append(files)
else:
    pass

for files in fmsFiles:
    run_Fms_Script = BashOperator(
        task_id="fms_script_"+files,
        bash_command='python3 '+scriptAirflow+'fmsScript.py "{{ execution_date }}"',
        dag=dag,
    )
    rerun_dag=TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='rerun_dag',
        trigger_dag_id='lv-manuf2020',
        trigger_rule='none_failed',
        dag=dag,
    )
    run_scripts.set_downstream(run_Fms_Script)
    rerun_dag.set_upstream(run_Fms_Script)

for files in memFiles:
    run_Mem_Script = BashOperator(
        task_id="mem_script_"+files,
        bash_command='python3 '+scriptAirflow+'memShScript.py "{{ execution_date }}"',
        dag=dag,
    )
    rerun_dag=TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='rerun_dag',
        trigger_dag_id='lv-manuf2020',
        trigger_rule='none_failed',
        dag=dag,
    )
    run_scripts.set_downstream(run_Mem_Script)
    rerun_dag.set_upstream(run_Mem_Script)






move_csv.set_upstream(file_sensor)
run_scripts.set_upstream(move_csv)
no_script.set_upstream(move_csv)
```

If you have any runtime errors related to `interpret_python` task, try to `cd` first to airflow's base path (`airflow.cfg` directory) and then call `python3` with the relative path.
For example, if airflow's path is `/home/username/airflow` and the dag is at `/home/username/airflow/dags/mydag.py`, define `interpret_python` as follows:

```
interpret_python = BashOperator(
    task_id="interpret_python",
    bash_command='cd /home/username/airflow && python3 dags/mydag.py',
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I create the interpret_python, when i start the Dag , interpret makes all next task skipped
What if i try a bash command to delete this .pyc?

Comment: The new tasks should be updated and seen in your airflow webserver visualization after few minutes and the next dagruns will run them (not the current which ran the interpret_python and added them).

Comment: You can also restart the webserver and scheduler to speed this process and don't forget to refresh the webserver page. What is your schedule_interval?

Comment: In fact, i think my problem is other, in "this bash_command='python3 '+scriptAirflow+'memShScript.py" , that script memShScript.py call a bash Script (with a subprocess.call), and my problem is that bashScript is never started. Python is well executed but not the bash script in it